# Updating Powerapps Global Variable property

Tags: powerapps

I have a global variable in PowerApps which I set onstart.

```
Set(CurrentItem, First(Filter('Internal Review', ID=Value(Param("ID")))))
```

This sets the variable CurrentItem to

```
{ myProperty: 1, secondProperty: 2 }
```

I want to update "myProperty" in the global variable on a button click. I've got this:

```
Set(CurrentItem, { myProperty: 3 })
```

but its not working.

Comment: I'm not sure you can update a variable in that manner. How about this: 
`Set(varCurrentItem, colProperties)`. Then update the Collection with a `Patch()` function?

Answer (score 2):

Try this
Set( CurrentItem, Patch( CurrentItem, {myProperty: 3 } ) )

Answer (score 0):

According to your formula, your global variable (CurrentItem) is bound to the "Internal Review" source. In your example it is currently { myProperty: 1, secondProperty: 2 } but it will change automatically if the respective values are changed in the source. You cannot change it because this would break the binding.
I would suggest to copy it and then apply the desired changes to the copy. Example: Set(CurrentItemCopy, { myProperty: CurrentItem.myProperty, secondProperty: 3 })